# Apache Phoenix Configuration Settings

Tags: hadoop, configuration, hbase, apache-phoenix, bigdata

I am trying to adjust the property values for some phoenix properties on hbase-site.xml. I am looking to adjust: ,

```
hbase.rpc.timeout   
phoenix.coprocessor.maxServerCacheTimeToLiveMs
hbase.client.scanner.timeout.period 
zookeeper.session.timeout   
phoenix.query.timeoutMs 
phoenix.query.keepAliveMs
```

Are there any guidelines to what i should set the value of these properties to? Depending on data size, number of nodes its running on, query complexity, etc. I know i need to change hbase.rpc.timeout aswell as phoenix.coprocessor.maxServerCacheTimeToLiveMs but im not entirely sure what i should set it to. Any help would be greatly appreciated!